# Converting C# code to VB.Net: no accessible 'Select' can be called with these arguments

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I tried to convert a C# code to VB language and I get the following error:

> Error 231 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select'
>   can be called with these arguments:
>       Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of System.Data.IDataRecord, Integer, TResult)) As
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature
>   that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of
>   System.Data.IDataRecord, Integer, TResult)'.
>       Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of System.Data.IDataRecord, Integer, TResult)) As
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot
>   be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s)
>   explicitly might correct this error.
>       Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of System.Data.IDataRecord, TResult)) As
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot
>   be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s)
>   explicitly might correct this error.  C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\SalesRepProject\SalesRep\Code\Job\JobInfoRepository.vb  25  13  SalesRep

Here is the code for C#:

```
 using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
       return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
           .Select(x => new JobInfo(){ 
               JobID = x.GetInt32(0), 
               Name = x.GetString(1), 
               LastExecutionDate = x.GetDateTime(2),  
               Status  = x.GetString(3) 
           }).ToList();
```

and here is the code for VB:

```
 Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    Return reader.Cast(Of IDataRecord)().[Select](Function(x) New JobInfo() With { _
        Key .JobID = x.GetInt32(0), _
        Key .Name = x.GetString(1), _
        Key .LastExecutionDate = x.GetDateTime(2), _
        Key .Status = x.GetString(3) _
    }).ToList()
```

any idea please. Thank you in advance

Comment: just remove that select

Comment: it gives me this error in the next bracket : Identifier expected.

Comment: do you mean the full select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what those `key` statement are for. I think this should do it:

```
Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
       Return reader.Cast(Of IDataRecord)().Select(Function(x) 
           New JobInfo() With {
               .JobID = x.GetInt32(0), 
               .Name = x.GetString(1), 
               .LastExecutionDate = x.GetDateTime(2), 
               .Status = x.GetString(3)
           }).ToList()
End Using
```

Comment: The online converters don't differentiate between collection initializers (this example) and anonymous types (where the 'Key' keyword is appropriate.